# Using range operator gives error predefined type 'System.range' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I discovered the range and index feature which was (apparently) released with c# 8 (`[1..4]` and `[^2]`) back in 2019 and I tried using them, but Visual Studio is giving me following errors in the editor:

```
CS0518: The predefined Typ "System.Range" is not defined or imported
CS0518: The predefined Typ "System.Index" is not defined or imported
```

(Note: I translated the errors as good as I can, the original errors are:

```
CS0518: Der vordefinierte Typ "System.Range" ist nicht definiert oder importiert
CS0518: Der vordefinierte Typ "System.Index" ist nicht definiert oder importiert
```

)

**My Code**

```cs
using System;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myArray = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
            Console.WriteLine(myArray[1..3].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I changed my Visual Studio LangVersion in the `.csproj` to `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>`

`dotnet --info` in cmd gives me following output:

```
.NET SDK (gemäß "global.json"):
 Version:   6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9
 Commit:    950e4949a7

Laufzeitumgebung:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18363
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7
  Commit:  bfd6048a60

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0-preview.4.21254.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Im using Visual Studio Community 2019 16.10.0

Comment: Besides changing the version.. do you have the C# 8.0 installed?

Comment: Just tested it, shows `System.Int32[]`, as expected.

Comment: How do I check if it's installed?

Comment: [This is a good read](https://dirkstrauss.com/enabling-c-8-in-visual-studio-2019) to find out how to enable 8.0 c# support. Check appropriate .Net is installed

Comment: @Jawad am I missing something or is he just changing the `<LangVersion>` in the csproj?

Comment: If you read through the link.. he is changing the langversion and asking you to install proper .net version on your system. without proper .Net, you are not going to get C# 8.0 or 9.0. I would suggest reading the entire page.